# Proving a convergent series defines an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume $ f\left(z\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n} $ converges on $D(0,r)$ which is a disk centered at the origin with radius $ r $.
How can I prove that $ f $ can be described as $ f\left(z\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}\left(z-z_{0}\right)^{n} $ for any $ z_0 \in D$ and with the maximal radius $r'$ such that $ D\left(z_{0},r'\right)\subset D\left(0,r\right) $?

What I thought is to show the obvious, using $ b_{n}=\frac{f^{(n)}\left(z_{0}\right)}{n!} $ and then to show that the reminder in the form of lagrange tends to $0 $. But, we have never proved lagrange reminder theorem for complex function so I feel uncomfortable with that, and besides, I feel like there's much more efficient way.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

(also, I'd prefer a way without line integrals, if exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct proof of the result above has three steps which I will outline as the computations/profs are standard

Step 1: using the usual results about expressing the radius of convergence in terms of coefficients,  the fact that a power series is uniformly and absolutely convergent on $|z| \le r_1 <r$ for any $r_1<r$, and the standard theorem about differentiating series of functions, one gets that for every $m \ge 1, f^{(m)}(z_0)$ is computable by differentiating the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}$ term by term, so it is

$f^{(m)}(z_0)=\sum_{n \ge m}n(n-1)...(n-m+1)a_nz_0^{n-m}$

Also one has $\sum_{n \ge 0}|a_n||w|^n < \infty, |w|<r$

Step 2: By the triangle inequality and the usual expansion of $(z_0+z)^n$, the double series $f(z_0+z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}(z_0+z)^{n}=\sum_{n \ge 0}(a_n\sum_{m=0}^nn(n-1)...(n-m+1)/m!a_nz_0^{n-m}z^m)$ is absolutely convergent for $|z_0|+|z|<r$ and uniformly convergent for $|z_0|+|z| \le r_1<r$ for any $r_1<r$, so can be rearranged at will, since absolute convergence reduces to the fact that

$\sum_{n \ge 0}|a_n|(|z_0|+|z|)^n < \infty$ for $|z_0|+|z|<r$ as in Step 1 above with $w=|z_o|+|z|<r$

Step 3: Changing the order of summation in the double series above and using Step 1, one immediately gets that $f(z_0+z)=\sum_{m \ge 0}f^{(m)}(z_0)z^m/m!$ as long as $|z_0|+|z|<r$ which is the required result substituting $z \to z-z_0$

Comment: Amazing. a few questions if I may. Why do we need $ |z_{0}|+|z|<r  $ ? you can change the summation also for $ z $ which satisfies $ |z_{0}+z|<r $. So why do we need the weaker condition on $ z $? Also, why do we need the argument about the uniform convergence? changing the order of summation can be done just because absolute convergence, isnt it?  Thanks.

Comment: When we use the triangle inequality everything (eg $z_0^kz^{n-k}$) gets in absolute value so we need $|z_0|+|z| <r$ and that is the right condition (here we prove the formula for $f(z_0+z)$ so if we substitute back $z \to z-z_0$ to express the result for $f(z)$ in terms of $z-z_0$, the condition becomes $|z-z_0|<r-|z_0|$, so $z$ is in the maximal disc centered at $z_0$ and contained in the original disc)

Comment: uniform convergence is useful in manipulating series of functions, so for example in proving that we can differentiate term by term the original series as many times as we want - if you accept that $f^{(m)}(z_0)=\sum_{n \ge m}n(n-1)...(n-m+1)a_nz_0^{n-m}$ then we do not need it later; in general the relation between uniform and absolute convergence is not as straightforward as here in the case of power series